# ImportError: cannot import name 'translate_sentence' from 'utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/utils/__init__.py)

Tags: python, import, nlp, google-colaboratory

I am using google colab for NLP. However, when I do my imports I keep getting the error
**ImportError: cannot import name 'translate_sentence' from 'utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/utils/**init**.py)**

Any help, please? Here are my imports

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import spacy
from utils import translate_sentence, bleu, save_checkpoint, load_checkpoint
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from torchtext.datasets import Multi30k
from torchtext.data import Field, BucketIterator
```

Answer (score 0):

The pylint convention asks users to import the standard libraries, then the third party libraries, and finally the modules in the local paths.
Also dividing direct import of functions and namespaces would help readability.

So the import sequence should be:

```py
import spacy
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from torchtext.datasets import Multi30k
from torchtext.data import Field, BucketIterator

from utils import translate_sentence, bleu, save_checkpoint, load_checkpoint
```

Which does not solve the import problem you have, but it makes clear that `utils` is not a third party library, but a local file that should be visible when executing the code.

Copy the `utils.py` file in the same folder and then add an empty `__init__.py` file if needed.