# Cannot import modules from utils in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

from utils import wordNum2word

I get this:

ImportError: cannot import name 'wordNum2word' from 'utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/utils/**init**.py)

Already !pip installed and upgrade utils, still have this error.
Using Colab. I have also followed this: [ImportError: cannot import name 'translate_sentence' from 'utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/utils/__init__.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67320239/importerror-cannot-import-name-translate-sentence-from-utils-usr-local-li)
but still not working.

I also cannot pip install wordNum2word directly. The error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wordNum2word (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wordNum2word

How should I fix this?

Comment: The `utils` unit in pypi, where `pip` gets its stuff, does not have a function like that.  My GUESS is that this module was provided by your class teacher.  This is an example of why such generic names are a terrible idea.

Comment: @TimRoberts I just found out the function is in the utils.py file in the utils folder, and my python is 3.10. So how should I import it from there?

Comment: If it is in `utils/utils.py`, then you need `from utils.utils import wordNum2word`.  Or, copy the file to the same folder as your script and do `from utils import...`.